# Proving an identity

Tags: calculus, integration, calculus-of-variations

Given $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$ and defining $F(z):=\int_0^z f(s) \, ds$ with $z \in \mathbb{R}$, how can one establish that $$F(a+b)=F(a)+f(a)b+ b^2\int_0^1 (1-s)f'(a+sb) \, ds,$$ which is part of a larger proof on page 508 of PDE Evans (2nd edition)?

Should I perform a change of variable to the second term on the RHS?

Comment: Are you sure the $f'(a+sb)$ term on the right side wasn't actually meant to be $f'(a+s(b-a))$?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Yes. For context, please refer to this PDF (http://www.mif.vu.lt/~algirdas/Evans.pdf) which is the Evans textbook, 1st edition. The proof is on PDF page 486 (textbook page 483), 5 lines from the bottom of that page..

Comment: Has to be a typo.  Try $f(x)=1.$    $LHS=b-a.$    $RHS =b$

Comment: Here is what Evans said: $$F(a+b)=F(a)+f(a)b+\int_0^1 (1-s)f'(a+sb) \, ds \, b^2.$$ Evans defined $F$ to be $F(z) := \int_0^z f(s) \, ds$, where $z \in \mathbb{R}$. Is this still a typo on the part of the author?

Comment: @dragon.  Not a typo by the author.

Comment: I started by saying $F(a+b)=F(a)+\int_a^b f(s) \, ds$, and then we are left to show that $$\int_a^b f(s) \, ds = f(a)b+\int_0^1 (1-s)f'(a+sb) \, ds \, b^2.$$ There must be something in my first presumption that is incorrect, which is what made the second "identity" fall apart.

Comment: Oh, so Evans' book is now freely available online? My paper copy is lost, so that'd be nice. If not, it does not look good with that link...

Comment: @mickep It has been online; I just found it with an ordinary search on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,
$$
F(a+b)-F(a)=\int_a^{a+b}f(t)\,dt.
$$
Then, integrate by parts,
$$
F(a+b)-F(a)=[(t-a-b)f(t)]_{a}^{a+b}-\int_a^{a+b}(t-a-b) f'(t)\,dt.
$$
Now, let $t=a+sb$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
F(a+b)-F(a)&=[(t-a-b)f(t)]_{a}^{a+b}+b^2\int_0^1 (1-s)f'(a+sb)\,ds\\
&=f(a)b+b^2\int_0^1 (1-s)f'(a+sb)\,ds.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: looks good! your integration by parts is particularly ingenious! using the function $t-a-b$ cuts out some irritating fiddling around. unless i've missed something you now have a very elegant and economical derivation! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

maybe useful to notice that if you take the author's relation:
$$
F(a+b)=F(a)+f(a)b+ b^2\int_0^1 (1-s)f'(a+sb) \, ds \
$$
and differentiate w.r.t $a$ you obtain
$$
f(a+b) = f(a)+ bf'(a) +b^2 \int_0^1 (1-s)f''(a+sb) \, ds \
$$
setting 
$$
I = b^2\int_0^1 (1-s)f''(a+sb) \, ds \
$$
we integrate by parts 
$$
I = [b(1-s)f'(a+sb)]_0^1 +b\int_0^1 f'(a+sb) \, ds \\
= -bf'(a) + f(a+b) -f(a)
$$
which is consistent. can you reverse the process?

---

**Edit by @dragon:**

Integration by parts establishes $$b^2 \int_0^1 (1-s) f''(a+sb) \, ds=-bf'(a)+f(a+b)-f(a).$$ So we have 
\begin{align}
f(a+b)&=f(a)+bf'(a)-bf'(a) + f(a+b) -f(a)\\&=f(a)+bf'(a)+b^2\int_0^1 (1-s) f''(a+sb) \, ds
\end{align}
Integrating both sides with respect to $a$, we obtain the textbook result $$F(a+b)=F(a)+bf(a)+b^2\int_0^1 (1-s) f'(a+sb) \, ds.$$

Comment: I have tried to reverse the process by adding this to your answer. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, that's the idea!(+1).

Comment: How can you switch derivative and integral on line 4?

Answer (score 0):

Taylor's formula with integral remainder: 
$$
F(a+b)=F(a) + F'(a) b + \int^{a+b}_a (a+b-t) F''(t)  \ dt
$$
Make a substitution $t=a+bs,$ and we get 
$$
F(a+b)=F(a) + F'(a) b + b^2\int^{1}_0 (1-s) F''(t) \ dt.
$$
Using $F(x)=\int^x_a f(w) \ dw,$ we get exactly the required result.